# Twitch API - reading url with json in Java

Tags: java, twitch

I want to get the streams that contains special tag (url: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=tag) and get stream's info, e.g. viewers, name, link to the stream. I tried very much, but none of the code I used worked. Can someone help me with this?

```
    try {
        String sURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft";

        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        String id = rootobj.get("_id").getAsString();
        System.out.println(id);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some code...

Comment: Ok, I just added the code.

Comment: BTW, it's still not clear what the problem is. Nevertheless see my working answer.

Comment: The problem is that this is not working at all. :) What answer? 

Edit: I'm looking at it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try 
        {
                    String sURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft";

                    URL url = new URL(sURL);
                    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    request.connect();

                    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
                    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
                    JsonArray streams = root.getAsJsonObject().get("streams").getAsJsonArray();
                    for (JsonElement stream : streams)
                    {
                        System.out.println(stream.getAsJsonObject().get("_id"));
                        JsonElement channel = stream.getAsJsonObject().get("channel");
                        System.out.println(channel.getAsJsonObject().get("display_name"));
                        System.out.println(channel.getAsJsonObject().get("url"));
                    }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The problem is that you try to get the _id from the root of your JSON result, but the structure has a streams member which contains all the streams.

HTH
Sal

Comment: It's working, I can get first 4 keys: game, viewers, created_at and _id. How to get the section channel and keys from it?

Comment: I want to read the next section "channel" and get "display_name" and "url" keys from there.

Comment: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/search.md#get-searchstreams

Comment: Thanks, It works! :D if I will have more problems with it i will message you. Thank you again. :)